# stack machine vs register machine example

Tags: java, android, stack, dalvik

I am trying to figure out the difference between a stack machine and a register based machine by an example:

stack machine would be like this:

### 1+2*3:

```
1.push 1 push 2 push 3
2.pop 3 pop 2 push 6
3.pop 6 pop 1
4.push 7
```

so we need many operations for the calculation above. Howe, in a register based machine, we don't have any push or pop operations, but the instruction need to have the registers of the operands.

Some the example would be like this:

```
R1(register) --> operand:1
R2 --> operand:2
R3 --> operand:3
```

How would be the equivalent operation in a register VM expressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In smali, which is an assembly language for the register based [dalvik bytecode](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html), it would be something like

```
const v0, 2        # v0 = 2
const v1, 3        # v1 = 3
mul-int v0, v0, v1 # v0 = v0 * v1
                   # v0 is now 6
const v1, 1        # v1 = 1
add-int v0, v0, v1 # v0 = v0 + v1
                   # v0 is now 7
```